# Postfix: disable local mail delivery

Tags: postfix

Whenever I e-mail "root", I want it to be forwarded to root@example.org (instead of a local delivery).

However, I keep getting this:

```
Feb  9 17:41:54 botmaster postfix/smtp[29969]: B6E0B808F5: to=<root@botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com loops back to myself)
```

This is my main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (by FlatTurtle)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mx.flatturtle.com
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 172.27.0.0/18 85.12.6.130/32
#mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relay_domains = /home/mx/postfix_transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550 

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
        check_policy_service unix:private/postgrey,
        permit
```

There are a few ways to disable local delivery, but none of them seem to be working (or at least, I keep getting that message).

dig mx flatturtle.com:

```
flatturtle.com.     14679   IN  MX  30 mx.flatturtle.com.
flatturtle.com.     14679   IN  MX  10 mail.flatturtle.com.
```

dig mx.flatturtle.com:

```
mx.flatturtle.com.          604800  IN  CNAME   mail2.rootspirit.com.
mail2.rootspirit.com.       21600   IN  CNAME   one.rootspirit.com.
one.rootspirit.com.         21600   IN  A       95.211.44.129
```

dig mail.flatturtle.com:

```
mail.flatturtle.com.    444387  IN  CNAME   mail.rootspirit.com.
mail.rootspirit.com.    10265   IN  A       85.12.6.130
```

dig flatturtle.com:

```
flatturtle.com.     14594   IN  A   85.12.6.130
```

dig botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com:

```
botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com. 4680 IN  A   95.211.44.129
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a work around by creating a new domain on the nameserver: "botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com".

The MX records point to another SMTP server.

Thus mailing root (which adds the @botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com domain) is forwarded and correctly delivered.

Answer (score 2):

"mail loops back to myself" has only one cause: postfix is sending out mail to a recipient domain that it is responsible for, such as RCPT TO: me@example.org, while $myhostname is the MX for example.org.

There is no configuration to fix this, since it is *what you configured*.

Add an alias for root to somewhere NOT on your postfix box, such as:

```
root:  you@other.example.com
```

Comment: This server is a backup MX server for about 150 domains (including "domain.tld"). $myhostname is actually set to servername.corp.domain.tld, /etc/alias is set to: root: root@domain.tld

Answer (score 2):

Postfix doesn't permit to send email to a destination SMTP server that have the same myhostname in SMTP banner. Then you must set current myhostname to backup.example.org or something else.

myhostname is a machine name, to avoid this problem you could set the MX server name to 'dexter.example.org' and the backup server name to 'deedee.example.org'. RFC 1178 says 'Use theme names'.

Comment: That's actually the case:

"myhostname = botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com" (I should've been more clear with "example.org")

Comment: Then you trying deliver by smtp to local IP. Check the DNS record for 'example.org' (test dns query from backup server) must point to primary server.

Comment: I've edited the original post with dig information (and used the real domains this time to avoid any more confusion).

Comment: when you send mail to 'user' without the domain, postfix add the value configured in option 'myorigin'. The alias_maps option is used to only by MDA 'postfix/local'. If you are senting mail by smtp, alias_maps isn't evoluated.

Comment: do not comment mydestination because the default value is $myhostname value. (use 'postconf -d mydestination' to see the default value). mydestination domains is locally delivered mails.

Comment: The background history: when you send mail to 'root', postfix add value from myorigin making root@botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com, how mydestination is commented, $myhostname is used as mydestination, then occurs 'mail loop back to myself, because postfix/smtp client detect $myhostname in connection banner, and trigger the error 'loop backup to myself' to avoid loops.

Comment: myorigin is set to botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com. I don't entirely understand what has to be changed for this to work.

Comment: set mydestination = localhost, but don't comment this option because default is $myhostname value. alias_map isn't processed by smtp client, remove it;

Comment: Still nothing. I've updated the above config/post with the new config.

Comment: please, change the myhostname to something.flatturtle.com. As I say on original anwser "Postfix doesn't permit to send email to a destination SMTP server that have the same myhostname in SMTP banner."

Comment: if you wanna disable delivery for botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com, you must add to transport_maps 'botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com error:local delivery is disabled'. local_transport is used by 'postfix/local' MDA that is for domains in mydestination.

Comment: I've set: "myhostname = botmaster.corp.flatturtle.com" -- is that okay?
I didn't quite catch the transport_maps thing. What do you mean? Transport_maps is not in the config file.